# How to set "absolute" area gradient?

Tags: java, android, teechart

See the image below. The gradient is painted incorrectly, and the vertical black lines are just ugly.

1. How do I create a gradient that stretches from `min` to `max`? E.g. If I have a scale from 0 to 100 I want my area to use N of these 0..100 gradient values.
2. How do I remove the vertical black lines?

[image: Bad gradient]

**UPDATE:** The provided answer works, except that I get this artifact:

[image: Artifact]

**UPDATE 2:** This only happens when using ONE `LinearLayout` as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/chart_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="3dip" >

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then the `TChart` is added to `chart_layout`. Bam! Offset error :)

Comment: Sorry, but I have forgotten ask you, if you could explain us what do you want achieve exactly, because we are clear what is your objective. 


Thanks,

Comment: I want the gradient to fade from minimum to maximum (0 to 100 in this case). So in the image above, points at 80 would have the 80th gradient color (almost green). Points at 50 would have the 50th gradient color (yellow). I believe you need a new gradient type: `SYMMETRICRECTGRADIENT`.

Comment: This is easily produced in Excel. Just create an area chart with a linear gradient fill color. Also, it supports multiple stops for the gradient. That's also a must-have :/

Comment: I've added the possibility to have multiple "stops" in a gradient to the wish list to be implemented in future releases (TJ71016471).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I create a gradient that stretches from min to max? E.g. If I have a scale from 0 to 100 I want my area to use N of these 0..100 gradient values.
>
> I want the gradient to fade from minimum to maximum (0 to 100 in this case). So in the image above, points at 80 would have the 80th gradient color (almost green). Points at 50 would have the 50th gradient color (yellow). I believe you need a new gradient type: SYMMETRICRECTGRADIENT

The Area series draws the segments one before the next, and the area below each segment with each of these segments. That's why the Area series can't draw a uniform gradient. However, the other versions of TeeChart have the GradientRelative that does what you request when it's set to false. I've added to the wish list the possibility to implement this property (and the functions associated) to the Java version (TJ71016477).

In the meanwhile, you could use the SeriesBand tool to do it. Here it is an example:

```
    tChart1.getAspect().setView3D(false);
    tChart1.getLegend().setVisible(false);

    Area area1 = new Area(tChart1.getChart());
    area1.fillSampleValues();
    area1.setOrigin(0);
    area1.setUseOrigin(true);
    area1.getAreaLines().setVisible(false);
    
    area1.getGradient().setVisible(false);
    area1.setColor(Color.transparent);
    
    SeriesBand band1 = new SeriesBand(tChart1.getChart());
    band1.setSeries(area1);
    band1.getGradient().setVisible(true);
    band1.getGradient().setDirection(GradientDirection.VERTICAL);
    band1.getGradient().setStartColor(Color.green);
    band1.getGradient().setMiddleColor(Color.yellow);
    band1.getGradient().setUseMiddle(true);
    band1.getGradient().setEndColor(Color.red);
```

This is what I get with the code above:

[image: Area with SeriesBand tool to show a uniform gradient]

**UPDATE:** I've reproduced the strange artifact issue. I've added to the wish list to be further investigated (TJ71016541).
In the meanwhile, using a second `LinearLayout` just for the chart seems to work fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="3dip" >

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/chart_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Another way around this, as said in the comments, is hiding the area line and making visible the SeriesBand pen:

```
area1.getLinePen().setVisible(false);
band1.getPen().setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Ok, almost works. The gradient looks nice, but I get a black border above the area. Actually, above the entire control. I'll post an image showing this error. I did try this: `band.getPen().setVisible(false);` but no success...

Comment: Also, `SeriesBand` does not work for `Bar` series! Nothing is drawn for one column and for multiple columns it draws some triangles...

Comment: I've edited the answer showing what I get here. I see no strange lines. Maybe you are using some different code?

Comment: Regarding the Bar series, please, create a new question since I think it will be a bit different. And please show what would be the expected result.

Comment: I believe the offset is caused by other controls *above* the TChart. Hence, if you add a button above the chart you should see this artifact. It's definitely a bug...

Comment: I've edited the answer again because I found the other versions have a GradientRelative property to do all this. Regarding the line above, I've added a Button above the chart and I still see everything fine. It may be the Android version (here trying with v4.2)

Comment: Can't see any other difference. Running 4.1.2 here.

Comment: The line offset matches the y-coordinate of the `TChart` exactly.

Comment: No problem in v4.1.2 here either.

Comment: You are right. We'll try to fix it for a future release. In the meanwhile, hiding the area line `area1.getLinePen().setVisible(false);` and making visible the SeriesBand pen `band1.getPen().setVisible(true);` seems to works fine for me here.

Answer (score 0):

**How do I create a gradient that stretches from min to max? E.g. If I
have a scale from 0 to 100 I want my area to use N of these 0..100
gradient values.**

I am afraid isn't possible do it using 0...100 gradients depending the scale, so the gradient of area is distributed throughout area using start, middle and end colors to draw the gradient.

**How do I remove the vertical black lines?**

To remove the vertical black lines, you only need set false the Area lines.

I hope will helps.

Thanks,

Comment: The lines are gone. Thanks :) Regarding the gradient, this is a must-have! Any chance this can be implemented or do I need to purchase the source code and implement it myself?

Comment: Try with a SeriesBand tool. I'll post a more complete reply.