# How center TChart header?

Tags: java, android, teechart

I have a `TChart` as shown below. I'm trying to center the header text, but no success.

```
chart.getHeader().setAlignment(StringAlignment.CENTER);
```

[image: Wrong center logic?]

That doesn't look centered to me. How do I center it on the surface instead of the left and right axes?

Comment: it seems it is in center of your chart, the problem is the legend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always align your title manually. Here you have an example:

```
tChart1.getAspect().setView3D(false);

Bar bar1 = new Bar(tChart1.getChart());
bar1.fillSampleValues();

tChart1.getPanel().setMarginUnits(PanelMarginUnits.PIXELS);
tChart1.getPanel().setMarginTop(30);

tChart1.getHeader().setCustomPosition(true);
tChart1.getHeader().setTop(7);    
int width = tChart1.getGraphics3D().textWidth(tChart1.getHeader().getText());
tChart1.getHeader().setLeft(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth()/2 - width/2);
```

Comment: A bit tedious, but it will suffice. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, this produces the same artifact as I mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014925/how-to-set-absolute-area-gradient The header text is placed on my other UI controls!

Comment: And I really consider this a bug since the footer does indeed center itself properly!

Comment: Regarding the "artifact" issue, the strings with custom position also seem to be displaced when using a "root" layout for the chart and a SeriesBand. I've also added this to the ticket that reports this "artifact" issue (TJ71016541). Regarding the footer, it seems to behave exactly as the header for me here.